# Encountering Internal server error 500 while uploading images to S3

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am facing an issue while uploading images to S3.I am using S3 class and jqueryimageuploader plugin for the same.
I have set up the basic application,and it worked well from my local machine.As I deployed it on beanstalk it started throwing the error.I have attached the console snapshot alongwith.
I am adding my code for reference here.[image]
This is the launching file index.html -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]"   data-url="http://mydomain.elasticbeanstalk.com/server/php/index.php" multiple>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
        });
    }
});
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
/* ... */
 progressall: function (e, data) {
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    $('#progress .bar').css(
        'width',
        progress + '%'
    );
  }
 });
});

</script>
<style>
.bar {
  height: 18px;
  background: green;
}
```

My index.php --> this is called on the file upload click

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
 require('UploadHandler.php');
 $upload_handler = new UploadHandler();

?>
```

The uploadHandler.php file can be found [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php)
I will add the portion modified by me for uploading to S3

```
$bucket = "my bucket nmae";
$s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
$response = $s3->putObjectFile($file_path,$bucket,$file->name,S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
$thumbResponse = $s3->putObjectFile('files/thumbnail/'.$file->name,$bucket,'images  /'.$file->name,S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
echo $response;
echo $thumbResponse;
if ($response==1) {
 echo 'HERER enter!!';
  } else {
      $file->error = "<strong>Something went wrong while uploading your    file... sorry.</strong>";
 }
```

I am not uploading too **big** files and it works fine on my local machine,but fails on beanstalk.Any help would be great.Thank you for the attention.

Comment: And your error logs say?

Comment: Check your server's error log. It'll have more details about the 500 (unless you're getting that 500 from amazon).

Comment: I configured the logs through console,but no error logged. :(

Comment: I have added the log info in the comments below.I am not able to find an issue there!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A HTTP 500 error means you have something "wrong" in your application that needs fixing (ie: it's the developer's fault as opposed to the user's fault like a 404)

To find out exactly what the issue is (there could honestly be 1000s of reasons why a HTTP 500 is generated) you will need to look at your error log files.  If it is using the standard LAMP stack you should be able to find this error log here: /var/log/apache2/error.log (but there could be many other locations)

My guess is that you have a file permissions issue.  I'm guessing that the user doesn't have write access to the folder you're trying to upload the images to in which case you will need to make that folder writeable (in Linux simply type: sudo chmod -R a+rwX /make/this/folder/something/writeable).  but again this is only a guess, you will need to double check your error log file first.

Comment: I am not sure if its the permissions issue as I uploaded the files via my local machine to the same folder.I went through the logs and there is nothing atleast in the amazon logs.I will go through the beanstalk log files and revert

Comment: This is what the logs say `::1 - - [08/Jul/2013:03:10:01 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.3 (Amazon) (internal dummy connection)"
10.164.47.96 - - [08/Jul/2013:03:10:52 +0000] "-" 408 - "-" "-"
``10.164.47.96 - - [08/Jul/2013:14:27:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 202 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36"
10.164.47.96 - - [08/Jul/2013:14:27:50 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: It was a developers fault to be honest! :P I had configured the path wrongly and did not cross check once uploaded to the server.Thank you for the response.

Comment: +1 In my case it was the incorrect database credentials, which resulted in other errors as well. Fixing login detail fixed the problem. Thx